# Yii Bootstrap Gridview Column headers is showing caret symbol

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

In YiiBootstrap `TbGridView`, the columns headers are defaulting with ^ for sorting like this.

Its mentioned in the file `\protected\extensions\bootstrap\widgets\TbDataColumn.php` on the line 28 like

```
if ($sort->resolveAttribute($this->name) !== false)
    $label .= '<span class="caret"></span>';
```

Because of this its showing as column header with down arrow next to the label.

I want my column headers not to have the caret symbol next to them, but I don't want to change this in the source widget as it would mean we would have issues updating the extension in future.

Is there any way to do this with the properties on the `TbGridView` widget itself?

Comment: I understand what YiiBootstrap is doing, and why you don't want to change it, but it's not clear what's wrong? Do you not want the caret? do you want to customise it?

Comment: Yes. I dont want that caret symbol appearing in the header. Is there any way to customize it in our coding instead of changing in the file TbDatacolumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to disable sorting on that column (which would get rid of it too), then your only way really is to use your own widget. As the `TbDataColumn` class is, for some reason, hard coded into the TbGridView. (you can see here [Source](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/src/b8ebaa303cc3/widgets/TbGridView.php?at=default#cl-105))

You can inherit from the `TbGridView`, override that function and replace it with a function that calls your `EDataColumn` class instead. Then you can do the same with the `ETbDataColumn` inherit from the `TbDataColumn` and just override the function you need.

e.g.

```
Yii::import('Bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView');
Yii::import('ext.widgets.ETbDataColumn');

/**
 * Bootstrap grid data column.
 */
class ETbGridView extends TbGridView
{

    public function createDataColumn($text)
    {
         if (!preg_match('/^([\w\.]+)(:(\w*))?(:(.*))?$/', $text, $matches))
                    throw new CException(Yii::t('zii', 'The column must be specified in the format of "Name:Type:Label", where "Type" and "Label" are optional.'));

            $column = new ETbDataColumn($this);
     ......
```

But if your feeling in a giving back mood, you can always alter the YiiBootstrap `TbGridView` to use a parameter to determine which column class to use, and submit a pull request to YiiBootstrap here: https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/pull-requests
To get the change put in the source code and solve this problem for everyone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that I am responding to an old question, but hope that this would help someone else looking for a solution. Here is how I worked around this issue:

Assuming that the original question is about hiding caret sign on columns that are not used in sorting, the following css changes should help to achieve the result without making extension source code changes.  I believe it is a bug to show caret sign on all sortable columns, instead caret sign should appear only on the columns used for sorting the current result set, and it should have the right direction.

```
.grid-view thead .caret {
    display: none;
}

.grid-view thead .asc .caret,
.grid-view thead .desc .caret {
    display: inline-block;
}

.grid-view thead .asc .caret {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
```